# Summary for the a specific branch

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I have a tensorflow graph that has a complicated loss function for the training, but a simpler one for evaluation (they share ancestors). Essentially this

```
train_op = ... (needs more things in feed_dict etc.)
acc = .... (just needs one value for placeholer)
```

to better understand what's going on, I added summaries. But calling

```
merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
```

and then

```
(summ, acc) = session.run([merged, acc_eval], feed_dict={..})
```

tensorflow complains that values for placeholders are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, to summary a specific tensorflow operation, you should run it specifically.

For example:

```
# define accuracy ops
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(Y, axis=1), tf.argmax(Y_labels, axis=1))  
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, dtype=tf.float32))  

# summary_accuracy is the Summary protocol buffer you need to run, 
# instead of merge_all(), if you want to summary specific ops
summary_accuracy = tf.summary.scalar('testing_accuracy', accuracy) 

# define writer file
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
test_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('log/test', sess.graph)

(summ, acc) = sess.run([summary_accuracy, accuracy], feed_dict={..})
test_writer.add_summary(summ)
```

Also, you can use `tf.summary.merge()`, [which is documented here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/merge).
Hope this help !